# Why does Windows 8.1 BSOD make my HDD (ST8000DM004) RAW whenever it occurs?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, bsod

I purchased a 8TB hard drive less than 30 days ago and because it was poorly packaged I tried to check it for bad sectors. 3 days later while the HDDScan was still doing a writing test my PC got a BSOD and after the computer restarted the HDD was gone from the 'My Computer' window I had to re-initialize it again (I had to choose a partition style between MBR and GPT all over again) and I always take GPT (I heard that's what I have to take since the drive is high capacity) and that happened to me twice. In both instance the HDD was connected via SATA to a USB 3.0 Docking Station. HDDScan found a large amount of bad sector and I though maybe that was it and I sent it back.

Less than 15 days ago I got a replacement drive same brand same model and well packaged. And I did the same thing again: checked it for bad sector by doing a write test using HDDScan (which could theorically take 8-10 days to fully test a 8TB) but 3 days in the computer BSOD again! (seems my computer can't stay on for 3 days in a row without BSOD-ing but that beside the point). When the computer restarted the disk was gone all over again, and again I had to re-init it. (again I took GPT)

Because HDDScan was finding bad sectors all over again I had to switch to a more serious tool (HD Tune Pro). Also for the fourth test (second test with the new drive) I connected it via SATA instead of using a docking station (USB). HD Tune found No bad sector (so obviously HDDScan sucks).

Happy with the HDD checks I did with HD Tune Pro I decided to copy files from my old 1TB (WDC WD10EACS) to my new 8TB. So I moved 100 GB worth of files and the remaining files I copied. But before I could copy every single files (I had copied some but not all), Windows BSOD-ed again. And when the computer loaded again the HDD was gone again and every file was gone with it! (basically I lost 100GB) worth of files. I GPT-ed once again and tried recovering them but the recovery software acted as if they were never there!

I don't know if it's Windows or the HDD model that is the issue. But I would really like to know what's causing this. (I don't think it's the way it is connected since I did both SATA and USB, also all the other connected drives are fine).

Comment: It's much more likely that whatever is causing your hard drive to become raw is what's causing Windows to BSOD.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator from what I've seen often time it is a USB issue. One time for instance it was a focusrite driver issue (it's an audio interface connected via usb). Other times there was the word usb in it but I don't recall exactly what it was. Anyway I will check at the next BSOD but if it's a USB related BSOD then it won't explain why the drive becomes raw while it's connected via SATA and why the other drives that are connected via USB are fine.

Comment: I think you should accept the findings of the tool that claimed defects on the disk.

Comment: @harrymc that tool says any disk is damage disk whereas when I tried HD Tune Pro on an actual damage disk it told me exactly how many blocks where damage and said nothing when I tried on the new drive. I am not saying you're wrong I am just looking for some other plausible solution. I will contact Seagate on monday anyway if I don't find an answer by then. Also I checked some of the files that I had copied on the 8TB and they seemed fine (the videos played fine at least and the pdf I opened worked as well)

Comment: @PaikuHan Are you sure that the USB 3.0 Docking Station works with disks as large as 8TB?

Comment: @AndrewMorton well from what I've seen it works. I mean I could see the entire 8TB and I even entirely filled the drive twice with a bunch of dummy files when I was testing it. But even if it wasn't that wouldn't explain why the drive become RAW even via SATA.

Comment: @PaikuHan I realise it'll take a long time, but does the drive pass the *manufacturer's* test software on SATA?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I didn't try on SATA but did on USB. Seatools (the manufacturer's test software for seagate) says it passed it with flying colors. I will try via SATA.

Comment: @PaikuHan Did you do the long test with SeaTools? (It take about 3 hours per terabyte.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yeah I did it took a whole day (I recall going to bed while it was running and it wasn't even finished when I woke up). The only reason I wanted to use another tool is because it doesn't seem to do writing test. From what I've seen it only does read test. (if it does writing test then I don't know how to do it).

Comment: @PaikuHan "seems my computer can't stay on for 3 days in a row without BSOD-ing but that beside the point" might be the entire problem.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yeah it's a very recent issue and like I said above, usually related to USB. Let's say it is. What next? I re-install windows, then months maybe years later I have the BSOD again and lose 5.5+ TB of data (which is the amount of data I need to transfer in). What I mean is knowing that the BSOD (if the BSOD is the reason why) is causing the drive to go RAW won't prevent it from happening again as it doesn't explain why other drives are not affected. Also it doesn't explain why only one is affected even via SATA (if really the BSOD is USB related. I'll have to check that!).